# Can't load Windows 7 after choosing it in the GRUB

Tags: grub2, windows-7

My laptop primarily came with Ubuntu 12.04, and I had a friend install Windows 7 ultimate for me. The grub used to work upon long pressing of the shift key when they system boots up. upon choosing the designated name for windows by enter key, Windows 7 would boot up.

This was all fine till last night. This morning, I installed all updates on Ubuntu, and then when i wanted to boot Windows, it isn't happening. No matter how many times I enter Grub and choose Windows, its only Ubuntu that's loading.

I need desperate help, please :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to run in a terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And paste here the output, then try to reboot again to Windows.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, my friend tried it! Help, please!!